# AppEngine timeout during firing of a task

Tags: java, google-app-engine, asynchronous

This scenario used to work for a few months: (what used to happen)
 1. API call, limited to 60 seconds
 2. I run some Endpoint API calls asynchronously through tasks, so I return a 'wait' message, to indicate to the caller to retry later
 3. The task is fired
 4.  The API call returns 'wait'
 5. The task continues to run

What happens now:
 1. The task is fired
2. The API does *NOT* return
 3. The task continues to run
 4. The API call times out

Here is the code I use:
1) 'Regular' API call (60 sec time limit)

```
      AsynchronousFire(operation, parameter);
```

2) AsynchronousFire

```
 @Override public void AsynchronousFire(Operation operation, Parameters parameter) {
    Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("asynchronous-command");
    byte[] bytes = ObjectSerializer.Serialize(parameter);
    String bytesMD5 = ObjectSerializer.getMD5(bytes);
    String userMD5 = ObjectSerializer.getMD5(parameter.getEmail().getBytes());
    String taskName = userMD5 + bytesMD5;
    if (this.executingTasksNames.containsKey(taskName)) {
      logger.warning("Task already exists --- Operation:" + operation + " taskName: " + taskName);
    } else {
      String encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
      TaskOptions taskOptions = TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/asynchronous_dispatch_command").
          param("taskName", taskName).
          param("operation", operation.toString()).
          param("parameters", encodedBytes);
      taskOptions.countdownMillis(0);
      TaskHandle taskHandle = queue.add(taskOptions);
      this.executingTasksNames.put(taskName, taskHandle.getName());
    }
  }
```

3) HTTP Servlet: asynchronous_dispatch_command

```
public class AsynchronousDispatchCommand extends HttpServlet {

  @Override public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    String operationName = request.getParameter("operation");
    String parametersEncoded = request.getParameter("parameters");
    byte[] parametersBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(parametersEncoded);
    Operation operation = Operation.fromString(operationName);
    Parameters parameters = (Parameters) ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(parametersBytes);
    controller.AsynchronousDispatch(request, operation, parameters, response);
  }
}
```

a. Is this code correct?
 b. This used to work reliably. What happened in the last 2 months that broke it?
 c. Is there a way to make this mechanism work reliably?

Thanks

Comment: Try removing the `countdownMillis(0);` line and using `queue.addAsync(taskOptions);` to see if you get different results.

Comment: That line of code was actually added a while back, since the tasks were fired unpredictably. At that time after I added the line, I may not have noticed. Thanks for the advise. I'll try that asap. I'll post the results.